# L805 Epson printer with all lights blinking

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

When I turn on the Epson printer L805, all the lights start to blink and it makes a strange noise from the inside.

According to the [manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd50133/source/printers/source/troubleshooting/reference/l805/problem_light_status_l805.html), it says that there are packing materials inside the printer.

I opened the cover, but there is no paper or other materials inside it. I turn OFF and then ON again, but the lights keep blinking.

It was printing normally and then it started to happen. The normal comportment is only the on and the wifi light on. The printer software says that the printer is unavailable and because of that I can't clean or align the cartridge. The printer is with paper and ink. 
I use original ink only.

Comment: If it's new return it. If it's under warranty get it serviced. It is difficult to diagnose hardware issues here.

Comment: Look for tiny pieces of paper or plastic inside the printer.